# What is causing my request to timeout?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, es6-promise, multer

I am trying to create a route that allows a user to upload a csv file, then asynchronously parses the file as Json and instantiates a model for each line. I have tried to use promises to do so, but the function request keeps timing out and I cannot see where it is breaking. Here is the code(/app/index):

```
const csv=require('csvtojson');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer().single(); 

router.post('/distributor/:id/upload', (req,res) => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
      if(err !== null) return reject(err);
      resolve();
    });
  })
  .then((req, res) => {
    return csv()
    .fromString(req.body.toString('utf8'))
    .on('json', (item) => { 
      item.distributor_id = req.params.id 
      Product
      .forge(item.body)
      .save()
      .then((product) => {
        res.json({id: product.id});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      })
    })
    .on('done', () => { 
      console.log('done parsing'); 
      resolve();
    });
  }) 
})
```

Here is the output from the heroku logs when I post a file to this route:

```
(node:49) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): undefined
2018-08-09T03:57:17.240599+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:49) [DEP0018] 
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the 
future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js 
process with a non-zero exit code.
2018-08-09T03:57:47.205596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 
desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/distributor/1/upload" host=fba- 
prof-prods.herokuapp.com request_id=40e1864b-fa71-49aa-8fdf-cedb1752edef 
fwd="73.92.68.83" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30284ms status=503 bytes=0 
protocol=https
```

If you could point me to any resources/examples where something similar is done correctly (handling upload and asynchronously parsing a large csv file), I would also greatly appreciate that. I am at a loss as to how to do this and can't seem to find any good resources! Thanks.

Comment: You need to reject/resolve your Promise - `new Promise((resolve, reject))` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Okay I changed that, but I am still getting the same result. I think that before some of my callbacks did not have a return value, but I think now they all do.

Comment: If it is a huge file chances are that network will timeout. You can increase network timeout req.setTimeout(600 * 1000) in your route.
this one will be alive for 10min

Comment: Thank you, @Sandeep. I have made some progress on this, but I am still not sure how I can get the file in a form where I can parse it. I have the updated details here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776343/how-can-i-parse-a-javascript-object-returned-by-multer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
function uploadAsync(req,res){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         upload(req,res,function(err){
             if(err !== null) return reject(err);
             resolve();
         });
    });
}
```

Note the `resolve()`. This is the key here since you are not doing anything with that Promise.

Comment: Okay I tried to incorporate that. I also updated my current logging output!

Comment: There are too many things here ... can you clean it up so you can go step by step. Like clean up everything in `.then((req, res) => {` and console.log stuff there. Lets make sure that that piece is working as expected before we chain the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Good idea @Akrion. I got rid of everything inside the .then((req, res) => {  call and replaced it with console.log(req). It did not log anything, and I still got the same output and timeout error, so I guess one issue must be in the first promise?

Comment: So this is since you are not passing anything to the `resolve()` so that you can get something in the `then` ... put a console.log(res) in the `upload(req,res,function(err)` function and see if that prints out anything ... then only pass what you need from that to the resolve() as a parameter and then you should get it in the `then`. See the Promise.resolve docs :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Thank you, @Akrion. I have made some progress on this, but I am still not sure how I can get the file in a form where I can parse it. I have the updated details here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776343/how-can-i-parse-a-javascript-object-returned-by-multer)

Comment: ok sounds good. Lets close this one and we can look at the other one.