# How can I parse a javascript object returned by multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express, multer

I am trying to use multer to handle upload of a csv file in express, then parse the file line by line. I am able to get the file as an object contained in req.body, but I am not able to parse it since it seems to now be just an object and no longer a csv string. How can I get each line from the uploaded file, individually? 
(app/index):

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

router.post('/distributor/:id/upload', upload.single(), function (req, res, 
next) {
  req.setTimeout(600000);
  console.log(req.body) 
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
    //calling req.body here returns an object with \r between each line from 
    file, but I cannot seem to parse each line
    res.end();
})
```

I tried to use csvtojson inside the second function, like this:

```
 csv()
.fromString(req.body.toString(UTF8))
.subscribe((csvLine)=>{
    console.log(csvLine); 
}
```

But this just tries to parse the whole object, not each line inside of it. Here is a snippet of the object that is returned by multer:

```
{"UPC,Price,SKU,Title\r\n043171884536,1.17,538397,ORANGE YARN EGGS SIZE 4 - 
4 PK\r\n043171080044,1.39,942227,MIKE'S YELLOW/CORN GLO 
BAIT\r\n035011000046,1.98,161687,REPLACEMENT BRAKE 
PADS\r\n056389001503,1.79,41582,FIRE 
LIGHTERS\r\n087837005156,5.04,266320,PLATINUM GREEN 1/4LB SPOOL 
25#\r\n046295070045,1.54,604652,MIKE'S GARLIC GLO-SCENT 
OIL\r\n043171660161,1.02,126011,THREAD  RED 100'\r"}
```

Edit** Before I was using bodyParser. I saw in an issue that using bodyParser with multer will not work, so I commented it out. Now, I don't get a body object, or a file object, or a files object. I tried using upload.none() and sending the same file in the request, to see if I could get it to error out with the message "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE", but it did not, so it seems multer does not even recognize that a file is being sent. I am testing this in Postman, with the content-type set to false and the body as binary with a file attached. Is there something wrong with trying to test the request that way?

Comment: `{"UPC,Price,SKU,Title\r\n…RED 100'\r"}` is not a valid object. Like `{"abc"}`, it is missing the value that would go after the key – an object would look like `{"abc": "def"}`. How exactly did you get that object returned by multer? And if you run `typeof thatValue`, does JavaScript say that the value is an object or a string?

Comment: @Rory O'Kane, i agree, that's whats tripping me up, but it' what i get when i console.log(req.body). If i call typeof, it says object, but i cant think of any normal object method that could retrieve the data inside it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example provided by the multer documentation, the req.body object will contain the text fields from the form, and req.file will contain the file that was uploaded:

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Have you tried using the `file` object? Something like the following:

```
router.post('/distributor/:id/upload', upload.single(), function (req, res, next) {
  req.setTimeout(600000);
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.file)
  csv()
  .fromFile(req.file.path)
  .then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
    //loop through array of objects here
  }) 
  next()
});
```

Comment: If I console.log req.file, it comes up undefined. My understanding from the multer docs is that req.file/files gets populated for nontext files, but for text-only files, the only thing that gets populated is req.body

Comment: Req.body contains the text from the file, but it's in a form where I cannot use it (as far as I know)

Comment: Before I was using bodyParser. I saw in another issue that using bodyParser with multer will not work, so I commented it out. Now, I don't get a body object, or a file object, or a files object. I tried using upload.none() and sending the same file in the request, to see if I could get it to error out with the message "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE", but it did not, so it seems multer does not even recognize that a file is being sent. I am using Postman, with the content-type set to false and the body as binary with a file attached. Is there something wrong with trying to test the request that way?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding is that multer is used for multipart form data. Can you try updating the content type to `multipart/form-data`? In the body tab, there should be a `form-data` radio button option you can select. You should then be able to select the `file` option in the drop down for Key and upload your file. Here's a link to a screen shot that shows this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29592177/28858454-4081e3fe-776e-11e7-8b73-3da8ad7b08f6.PNG. After updating your request in postman you should get the file object. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I stopped trying to test this in Postman and started testing it from my actual client, and now it's working. I think you are right, probably a problem with the encoding being sent via postman. Now I know for the future. Thanks!